# Why files do not reach the server?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have a `form`.

Everything works correctly and almost perfectly, but there is a problem.

The request goes to the correct route, but files are constantly not reaching the server.

The selected files get into the state from the target - this works. But in `formData`, where the `console.log` is, it's always empty.

I don't understand what's wrong?

API method:

```
export const uploadImage = async (heroId, image) => {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('images', image);

  return await httpClient.post(`/superheroes/${heroId}/images`, formData);
};
```

Form:

```
<Formik
        initialValues={{ images: [] }}
        onSubmit={async (values, { setSubmitting }) => {
            const formData = new FormData();
            values.images.forEach((file) => {
                formData.append("images", file);
            });
            try {
                console.log([...formData.entries()]);
                await uploadImage(hero.id, formData);
                //dispatch(getHeroes());
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            } finally {
                setSubmitting(false); // unblock form submission after file upload
            }
        }}
    >
        {({ setFieldValue, isSubmitting }) => (
            <Form>
                <div>
                    <label>Images:</label>
                    <input
                        type="file"
                        id="images"
                        name="images"
                        multiple
                        onChange={(event) =>
                            setFieldValue("images", [...event.target.files])
                        }
                    />
                    <ErrorMessage name="images" className="error" component="div" />
                </div>
                <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>
                    Submit
                </button>
            </Form>
        )}
    </Formik>
```

UPD.
I was outputting the values to the console a bit incorrectly. formData in place console.log comes. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: what is `FormData`?

Comment: @HasanAga, An object for working with files. Right?

Comment: where does it come from? I quickly looked at the Formik docs but couldnt find it. if you can refer to it maybe I can understand what it does.

Comment: @HasanAga, This is a webAPI interface, you can read about it on MDN

Comment: `formData.getAll("images")` will return the files correctly. Maybe try put it in `uploadImage` function?

Comment: @LynnC. I tried - it didn't work. I added an API method. Maybe there is an error?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49467557/21562825) may help? Using `fetch` API to post.